# Xcode 6 storyboard does not show my views

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

The storyboard of my Xcode makes my views invisible (disappearing, vanishing) after I exit and re-open the project.

I can add a view, edit it, add components to it. But once Saved, the view will not be present anymore in the storyboard if I restart the program. The main view will be visible, the connections (segues) to other views will be visible, but not the descendants view. They will be like invisible and locked to their position.

I attach a picture as reference.

[image: Main storyboard with invisible views]

[image: After the comment, here is the same view, no errors, still invisible views]

I thought it was due to the width/height settings, but enforcing these values to be similar to the main view ones does not fix the problem.

Any clue?

Comment: The red exclamation mark in the upper right corner indicates an error. What does it say?

Comment: Hello @zisoft . The error was due to my multiple tests. I have added code and views to just test the bug. I now have removed the new random stuff I have added and as you can see from the new screenshot the problem still persists.

Comment: In the Document Outline on the left (out of the picture), select a "missing" scene. What happens?

Comment: Nothing. The storyboard centers on the arrow's end pointing to that scene. But nothing is there. I can add new views, but then they will disappear at reboot.

Comment: Are you using size classes? Do you sometimes edit for just one particular size class?

Comment: Also what kind of segues are those?

Comment: I am using the automatic settings of the Storyboard editor (e.g. wCompact, hAny) and I did not set a specified height and width in the View Controller "content size" preferences.

Strangely though, if I add a View controller and I do not attach it to any code (via outlets) the view stays there... As soon as I connect it to some code, it vanishes.

Comment: The segues are all "popover presentation"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Check ViewController Width and Height , it is possible only when height and width both are 0.

Let me know if it works.

Comment: OK. This is WEIRD. Your solution fix the issue (and is accepted as answer, [in your face Apple Developer forum]).
Howevre, this seems wrong! Why should I fix all sizes manually?When Freeform is selected and the system is all in auto (auto Layout and auto size classes), and I select my layout size from the footer of the storyboard (wCompact / hAny) Xcode should be smart enough to adapt my views... I am puzzled.